# jQuery scrollTop only works once

Tags: jquery

I am using this bit of code to open a div and scroll down to it. It works well, but only the first time I use it, even on page refresh it will not work again. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Here is the URL([www.patrickorr.ca](http://www.patrickorr.ca))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.ftropen")
    .click(function(){
        $("div#connect").animate({height: "500px" }, "fast");                                              
        $("div#ftrconnect").fadeOut("fast");  //hide connectbtn
        $("div#ftrhide").fadeIn("fast");  //show hidebtn
        $("#connect").scrollTop($("#connect").scrollTop() + 500);
    return false;
});
$("div.ftrclose")
    .click(function(){
        $("div#connect").animate({height: "0px" }, "fast");                                            
        $("div#ftrhide").fadeOut("fast");  //hide hidebtn
        $("div#ftrconnect").fadeIn("fast");  //show connectbtn
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the `jquery.anchor.js` library that is giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null jquery.anchor.js:32` in Chrome 14. I have commented it out and replaced the *open* function with:

```
$("div.ftropen").click(function(){
    $("div#connect").animate({height: "500px" }, "fast", function() {
        $("body").scrollTop( $("#connect").position().top);
    });                                    
    $("div#ftrconnect").fadeOut("fast");  //hide connectbtn
    $("div#ftrhide").fadeIn("fast");  //show hidebtn
    return false;
});
```

that scrolls the body to the top of the `<div id="connect">`

<strike>I'll see if I can get the anchor animate plugin working…</strike>

Actually the [Anchor Slider](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/) plugin seems to be interfering with your `<div>` click events completely. The `<a>` click is occurring first and consuming the event. I think that you need to decide to use the Anchor Slider plugin to animate the "scroll to" or the jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in your code.

**Edit:** If you remove the `jquery.anchor.js` script, use the following *target*

```
<div id="connect" style="height:0px; display:block;"><a style="display:block;margin-top:500px;height:100px;" id="target" name="target">f</a></div>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.ftropen').click(function(event){
        $('div#connect').animate({height: '500px' }, 'fast', function() {
            $('body').animate({scrollTop : $('#target').position().top + 500}, 700);
        });
        $('div#ftrconnect').fadeOut('fast');  //hide connectbtn
        $('div#ftrhide').fadeIn('fast');  //show hidebtn
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
    $('div.ftrclose')
        .click(function(){
            $('div#connect').animate({height: '0px' }, 'fast');
            $('div#ftrhide').fadeOut('fast');  //hide hidebtn
            $('div#ftrconnect').fadeIn('fast');  //show connectbtn
        return false;
    });
});
```

which animates the *scroll to* the `<a id="target">` when the `<div>` height animate has completed.

**Edit2:** [**Added a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C5SGW/5/).

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunatly I can't get either of your solutions to auto scroll to the bottom of the div that opens. It doesn't appear to be working in the JS fiddle either. 

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Fixed demo link that now scrolls to the bottom of the div that opens.

Comment: also, without the jquery.anchor.js plugin active then the <a href="target" tries linking to an external page...

Comment: Thanks andy, did the link change, still getting same results in jsfiddle.

Comment: The demo that scrolls to the bottom correctly is http://jsfiddle.net/C5SGW/2/ and you could remove the anchors if the `<div>` is handling the opening/closing and scrolling. Unless there is another reason you need them?

Comment: That JSfiddle is not showing the screen position scrolling down to accommodating the expanding div.

Comment: Seems to be working OK for me in Chrome. There is nothing that should make it not work in other browsers though. Can anyone else try it please?

Comment: no you're right, that does work in chrome, not firefox though:( Sorry, I always debug with firebug. Wonder why tho, that doesn't make sense.

***Does work in safari, but not in IE.

Comment: Ah, damn sorry. I should have tested it in more than one browser.

Comment: Right, based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042651/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-in-chrome-but-working-in-firefox/3042875#3042875, I have updated the demo link. Now works in Firefox :-)

Comment: ahhh html, body. Thats a billion andy.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    $("body").animate({
```

Use the following

```
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
```

BODY and HTML are treated differently by Mozilla and Webkit browsers. So covering off both will help. Also introduce the :not(:animated) declaraction. JS for the animation to scroll to position would end up being something like...

```
    $('#DIV a[href^=#]').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var h = $(this).attr('href');
       $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: $(h).offset().top }, 1200);
    });
```