# Smooth Scroll Javascript Breaks Internal Links, Only In Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, smooth-scrolling, internal-link

I have a one-page website built on Bootstrap. All of the menu items are internal links pointing to divs in the body, and I have a bit of smooth scroll javascript to animate page's scrolling.

Everything works fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the links don't work at all. It seems like a Javascript issue, because if I comment out the lines referring to the smoothscroll .js file, then the links work fine.

The javascript that I'm using is this:

```
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
if($(this).attr('href').indexOf("#") == 0) {
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetOffset = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset - 70}, 700);
  });
}
});
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

You can take a look at the actual site in question [here](http://stopgorec.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scrollTop animation to

```
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset - 70}, 700);
```

That should fix it in FF an also still work in Chrome.

***update***

Just in case you're asking why: I don't know for sure, so this is what I guess is happening: if you compare the `HTML` and `BODY` in FF and Chrome, in FF the size of the `HTML`-Element is as big as your rendered document. In Chrome your `HTML`-Element has the size of the Browser-Window and your `BODY`-Element is as big as your Page rendered. They render differently. FF scrolls the `HTML` inside its Window and Chrome scrolls the `BODY` inside the `HTML`.

As pointed out in other threads / comments ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042651/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-in-chrome-but-working-in-firefox#comment12428574_3042875) for expample) this solution makes two calls. So you could put an `if` before scrolling or use `document`. The latter didn't do the trick for me, because it scrolled where I wanted it to scroll to, but didn't animate. Without `if` I personally just find it nicer to read and it shouldn't be such a big thing to call animate twice in that case. So the better solution would be detecting the browser and using either `$('html')` or `$('body')`.