# JS works in Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome. Here's my site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have just one function in my app.js file. The site functions in FFox and Safari, but not Chrome. Has anyone run into this before or have any guesses at a solution?

[http://www.codewithsarah.com][1]

Comment: You are going to get down votes for questions like these. Show your code; ask your specific question(s); and comment. Let's try this again.

Comment: No need to be snarky. As most people know, dev tools reveals code. My specific question is quite simple. If I had merely included code, I would have been asked to make a fiddle. Instead I produced the live site, and I got a helpful reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, place a debug statement in there somewhere to make sure that your function is being actually invoked.

Second, there is potentially a problem with scrollTop() in Chrome. For instance, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042651/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-in-chrome-but-working-in-firefox).

Comment: Appreciate the help @amahfouz