# Scrolling page section with mouse wheel doesn't work in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll, mousewheel, browser-bugs

I want to use [this](http://videsignz.com/testing/divscrolling.php) effect on my site but this code works only in Firefox. I can't find what's wrong, can you help me, please?

Comment: Have you tried [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)? It is what people use for this kind of sites.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that not enough reputation to put this in comments.

Please refer to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042651/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-in-chrome-but-working-in-firefox). You should use `$("html,body")` instead of `$("html")`.

Answered cannot be verified using my current public PC. Please inform me if this is not working, and I will delete the post.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)
Unfortunatelly it still doesn't work in this crap :(
How can I rewrite this code? Or where can I get similiar? I check a few codes but this works best until I tried it in this "great" browser. It's not my first problem with chrome -.-